# Im getting an invalid syntax error where it says value=self.amt

Tags: python

```
class Gold(Item):
    def __init__(self, amt):
        self.amt = amt
        super().__init__(name="Gold",
                         description="A round coin with {} stamped on the front.".format(str(self.amt))
                         value=self.amt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten a `,` after your `.format()`